# Is running SSIS package using SQL Server 2008 Job possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Is running SSIS package using SQL Server 2008 Job possible? If it is possible, can someone teach me the proper way to do it or give me some best links that provides best solutions or tutorial? Thank you so much. I'm learning SSIS now and i need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a SQL Agent Job. Add a job step with a subsystem of type `SQL Server Integration Services`. You will then need to select the package location which is dependent upon whether you have it stored on the file system, the SSIS package store or a SQL Server.

If you are using resources that are only available in 32 bit mode (Excel, Access, etc) then you will need to go to the advanced tab and check the Run in 32 bit mode button.